# How can I notify a specific group in Laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have a problem, I want to notify specific users, like a group of users or admins for example. But I don't know how I can only notify admin or users in my code with Laravel.

Here is my `AdsController.php` in which I notify only admin:

```
$ads = new Ad;
$current_user=Auth::user();
$ads->object = $request->input('object');
$ads->description = $request->input('description');

$ads->save();

$users = User::where('id', '<>', $current_user->id)->where('admin', 1)->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {

    $user->notify(new NewAd($current_user, $ads));

}
```

please someone help me

Comment: Why not add a `user_level` field in the DB and assign int values? example: 1: users, 2, admins then just just run a `->where('user_level', $value)`

Answer (score 0):

you can add 1 table calls "role", and on table users add 1 field calls role_id. and then you can make condition in your controller, 
for example :

**Role table**
id | name
1  | Admin
2  | User

**User table**
id | name | role_id
1  | Jon  | 1
2  | Doe  |2

**Data table**
id | name |user_id
1  |Data1  |  1
2  |Data2  | 2

Controller

```
 public function index() {

    if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1 ){
        $datas = Data::all();
        return view('projects.index',['datas' => $datas]);           
    } else {
        $datas = DB::table('datas')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id )->get();
        return view('projects.index',['datas' => $datas]);

    }
```

Hope can help you

Comment: i already  have a field call admin =1 if i notify the admins ,else if admin filed=0 then i notify the users only.

Comment: but my problem is how can i choose to notify a group of users or admins

Comment: Are you add role_id fields on users tabel? and set thats fields as foreignkey?

Comment: no i just add a radio button on the ad.blade.php and when i make the ad i choose if i will send it to the admin or user,it work for the admin and the user but i want to notify a users wich i choose them ,do y indresta,nd me.